# How to use relative path in Python

Tags: python, path

I want to use a relative path to send a folder with csv files.
The notebook is saved in the same folder as the csv files.
I tried following code but a FileNotFoundError results.

train = pd.read_csv("../train.csv",delimiter='|')

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", delimiter='|')
```

Comment: What is the organization of your folders and files?

Comment: the folder is placed on the desktop. the csv file and the ipynb file are in this folder without any subfolders

Comment: Add in your notebook: `import os` then `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Well there's no secrets, if you have a FileNotFoundError, it means that the file... is not found. Try using `os.listdir('.')` to see the content of your current working directory. Try opening the file and directly read it without pandas to see if it exists and to check if there is actual content.

Comment: thanks for your help. The notebook isn´t searching for the csv file in the same folder I saved it, it is searching in the level above

Comment: Yes, that's why I changed "../train.csv" to "train.csv" :) Consider accepting my answer if it helped you